# rEFInd Linux Kernel Boot Options

Tags: unix, kernel, efi

When booting opensuse via rEFInd, the kernel options are wrong (the root device name is incorrect).

Where do the kernel arguments that rEFInd is using come from, and how do I modify them? The line I'm looking for is of the form

```
ro root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-APPLE_SSD_SM768E_S119NYAC612 initrd=boot\initrd-3.7.xxx-default
```

The `root` argument should be

```
ata-APPLE_SSD_SM768E_S119NYAC612130-part7
```

as that is where the SUSE root partition is. If I edit the boot options from the rEFInd menu (higlight the SUSE entry, hit F2, hit F2 again on the default entry) and modify the options to include the `130-part7` suffix, everything works fine. If not, Linux asks me:

> Could not find /dev/disk/by-id/ata-APPLE_SSD_SM768E_S119NYAC612.
>   Want me to fall back to
>   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-APPLE_SSD_SM768E_S119NYAC612130-part7? (Y/n)

I'd happily hit "Y" here and move on but, unfortunately, the keyboard doesn't work at this stage in the boot process. If I attach a USB keyboard, it works, but I really don't want to carry one around with me. (Perhaps there is a market for a one-key USB keyboard that can be programmed for these things. Dear God...)

So, I am left changing the options via the rEFInd menu every time I boot Linux.

I'd thought about adding a symlink directing `...612` to `...612130-part7`, but the links in `/dev/disk/by-id/` are stored in tempfs (ie, not persistent). Also, that is a crappy solution.

Help?!

Comment: I am running Bootcamp with Lion 10.8 and rEFit with 10.7, however I also have a rEFit box with 10.6 on it.  Happy to play with rEFind and SuSE to help you out, just need to know what versions of everything you are running?  So: version of Mac OS X, version of rEFind, and version of SuSE?

Comment: @Deesbek suse 12.3 x64, ML 10.8.6, not sure about the refind rev but I downloaded it about a week ago for a rebuild. Thanks for your help. This is on a mod-2012 MBP Retina, 16GB,  768SSD yada yada.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [awesome Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_parameters#rEFInd):

> To make the change persistent after reboot, edit /boot/refind_linux.conf and append them between the quotes in all required lines, for example
>
> "Boot using default options"   "root=UUID=0a3407de-014b-458b-b5c1-848e92a327a3 rw quiet splash"